# Domain name replaced by upstream name in Nginx/uWSGI/Django stack

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I moved an old Django-based website from an old and insecure server.

Because of software dependencies, it is not possible to update the Django version from 1.x.

Everything worked fine on the old server, but after moving to a new server the domain name gets replaced with the `proxy_pass` upstream name (`keepalive`) from Nginx whenever the site makes an `HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(...))`, so `https://example.com/somewhere/` becomes `https://keepalive/somewhere/`.

When this happens, the access is not recorded by the uWSGI server, but I can then change the URL in the browser, and that works.

The Nginx site config looks like this:

```
upstream keepalive {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
    keepalive 64;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;

    ssl_certificate /var/www/example.com/config/server.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/example.com/config/server.key;
    
    location /static/ {
        alias /var/www/example.com/example/static/static_root/;
    }
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://keepalive;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }
    
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example_error.log info;
}
```

**--- UPDATE ---**

If I map my local port 9000 to 9000 (the upstream port) on the server like this:

```
ssh 9000:127.0.0.1:9000 user@example.com
```

I can access the site at `127.0.0.1:9000` without any problem whatsoever.

To me, this confirms that the problem lies with Nginx.

**--- UPDATE 2 ---**

So it turns out that this combination does the trick:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://keepalive;
}
```

Comment: What redirect result  curl/wget of  http://keepalive; URL directly ( type and redirect value), also what is exact version of Django you are using.

Comment: @iklinac I don't understand what you mean - `keepalive` is not a valid name outside the Nginx config. Also, see my update accessing the upstream directly. The Django version is 1.8.2.

Comment: You could try adding `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;` `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;` and `proxy_redirect off;` to `location /` before `proxy_pass`. Also keep in mind that all `proxy_set_header` configs should be above `proxy_pass`. Alternatively you can use `include proxy_params;` to automatically include all proxy headers.